Skip rebase step on conflict with Libgit2sharp
I am performing a rebase operation with libgit2sharp and it works all nice, but
I and would like to skip a rebase step when a conflict occurs (if the commit has a specific message)

rebaseResult = _repository.Rebase.Start(branch, GetBranch(requiredBaseBranch),  null, new Identity(_configuration.CommitUserName, _configuration.CommitEmailAddress), options);
if (rebaseResult.Status == RebaseStatus.Complete)
    return true;
else
{
    if (rebaseResult.Status == RebaseStatus.Conflicts)
    {
        var currentStep = _repository.Rebase.GetCurrentStepInfo();

        if (currentStep.Commit.Message.Trim().EndsWith("Update packages", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //is it possible to somehow skip and continue?
        }
    }
}

Is it possible?
I had a look and the API doesn't seem to support it directly, but perhaps there is some more convoluted way to achieve this...

you can clean your staging area and amend current commit. with no changes the commit will disappear

I ended up writing a small command line based class that skips the rebase.
Posting the full solution that worked for me, for future reference:
public class PoorManRebaseMachine
{
    private readonly Action<string, ConsoleColor> _logDelegate;
    private readonly string _localRepoPath;

    public PoorManRebaseMachine(string localRepoPath, Action<string, ConsoleColor> logDelegate)
    {
        _logDelegate = logDelegate;
        _localRepoPath = localRepoPath;
    }

    public bool TryPoorManRebase(string storyNumber)
    {
        var errorOutput = RunGitCommandProcess("rebase master");
      
        if (IsUpdatePackagesRebaseConflict(errorOutput, storyNumber))
        {
            try
            {
                return TrySkippingUpdatePackagesCommitsRecursive(storyNumber, errorOutput);
            }
            catch ( ex)
            {
                _logDelegate($" while attempting automated rebase: {ex}", ConsoleColor.Red);
                return false;
            }
        }

        _logDelegate($"Will not attempt automated rebase due to a conflict not resolvable automatically: {errorOutput}", ConsoleColor.Red);
        return false;

    }

    private bool TrySkippingUpdatePackagesCommitsRecursive(string storyNumber, string lastError)
    {
        if (IsUpdatePackagesRebaseConflict(lastError, storyNumber))
        {
            _logDelegate($"{GetRebaseStepNumber(lastError)} - Skipping rebase of: {GetRebaseConflictInfo(lastError)}", ConsoleColor.Cyan);

            var errorOutput = RunGitCommandProcess("rebase --skip");

            if (errorOutput.Contains("Successfully rebased and updated"))
            {
                _logDelegate($"Automated rebase done: {errorOutput}", ConsoleColor.Green);
                return true;
            }
            _logDelegate($"{GetRebaseStepNumber(lastError)} - DONE, Starting {GetRebaseStepNumber(errorOutput)}", ConsoleColor.DarkCyan);

            return TrySkippingUpdatePackagesCommitsRecursive(storyNumber, errorOutput);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperation($"The rebase conflict {lastError} cannot be solved automatically");
    }

    private static bool IsUpdatePackagesRebaseConflict(string conflictMessage, string storyNumber) => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(conflictMessage, $"Could not apply .+... {storyNumber}[ -]*Update packages");

    private static string GetRebaseStepNumber(string conflictMessage) => conflictMessage.Split(['\r', '\n'], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();

    private static string GetRebaseConflictInfo(string conflictMessage)
    {
        var line = conflictMessage.Split(['\r', '\n'], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).LastOrDefault();
        return line?.Replace("Could not apply ", "");
    }

    private string RunGitCommandProcess(string commandName)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        var si = new ProcessStartInfo("git", commandName)
        {
            WorkingDirectory = _localRepoPath,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
        p.StartInfo = si;
        p.Start();
        _ = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //need to read output, as without it sometimes the process hangs on reading error
        var errorOutput = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        return errorOutput;
    }
}

